# Java 2D game, game map and rectangle movement

Tags: java, collision-detection, rectangles

**The Game**

I have coded a simple Java game where there is a overhead view of a player on a 2D map that moves with the keyboard arrow input (up, down, left, right), my Play class that holds all of my game code is made up of a few methods, init which holds the initial game options things such as what way the player should be facing when the game starts, render which draws everything onto the screen such as the actual player and map, update which deals with the keyboard inputs and moving the player, when I say move the player, in this game it really is move the map, as the map is so big I needed the player to be able to walk around the map and the screen follow it and the simplest way of doing that was keeping the player still and moving the map creating the illusion that the player is actually moving.

**The Problem**

Everything works fine apart from the map, the map is a large 2D image, it has obstacles such as houses on it, at the moment the player just walks through the houses and other obstacles (lets concentrate on just the house for now), I need the game to stop the player from walking through the house. So I planned on using the simple rectangle collision detection and simply change the direction of the player if the collision occurred, so I tried making the two rectangles but a problem occurred, when I draw the rectangles on the screen using the render method (one above the player(rectOne), another above the house(rectTwo)) it doesn't exactly go to plan, when playing the game when I try move one rectangle the other follows it, this is a problem because how is there ever supposed to be a collision of the two rectangles move at the same time.

**The Code**

The code shown is a simplified version of the Play class that holds all of the game code:

```
    imports are here
    public class Play extends BasicGameState{
    Animation bucky, movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight;
    Image worldMap;
    int[] duration = {200, 200};//how long frame stays up for
    float buckyPositionX = 0;
    float buckyPositionY = 0;
    float shiftX = buckyPositionX + 320;//keeps user in the middle of the screem
    float shiftY = buckyPositionY + 160;//the numbers are half of the screen size
    java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float rectOne = new Rectangle2D.Float(shiftX, shiftY,90,90);
    java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float rectTwo = new Rectangle2D.Float(500 + buckyPositionX, 330 + buckyPositionY, 210, 150);
    public Play(int state){
    }   
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
          worldMap = new Image("res/world.png");
          Image[] walkUp = {new Image("res/b.png"), new Image("res/b.png")}; //these are the images to be used in the "walkUp" animation
          Image[] walkDown = {new Image("res/f.png"), new Image("res/f.png")};
          Image[] walkLeft = {new Image("res/l.png"), new Image("res/l.png")};
          Image[] walkRight = {new Image("res/r.png"), new Image("res/r.png")};
    movingUp = new Animation(walkUp, duration, false);
    movingDown = new Animation(walkDown, duration, false);  
    movingLeft = new Animation(walkLeft, duration, false);  
    movingRight = new Animation(walkRight, duration, false);
    bucky = movingDown;//facing screen initially on startup
    }
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
    worldMap.draw(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY);//position 0,0
    bucky.draw(shiftX, shiftY);//makes him appear at center of map
    g.fillRect((float)rectOne.getX(), (float)rectOne.getY(), (float)rectOne.getWidth(), (float)rectOne.getHeight());
    g.fillRect((float)rectTwo.getX(), (float)rectTwo.getY(), (float)rectTwo.getWidth(), (float)rectTwo.getHeight());
}
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    //up
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
        bucky = movingUp;//changes the image to his back
        buckyPositionY += 2;;//increase the Y coordinates of bucky (move him up)
        if(buckyPositionY>162){//if I reach the top 
            buckyPositionY -= 2;//stops any further movement in that direction
        }
    }
    //down
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
        bucky = movingDown;
        buckyPositionY -= 2;
        if(buckyPositionY<-550){
            buckyPositionY += 2;//basically change the direction if + make -
    }}
    //left
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
        bucky = movingLeft;
        buckyPositionX += 2;
        if(buckyPositionX>324){
            buckyPositionX -= 2;//delta * .1f
    }}
    //right
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
        bucky = movingRight;
        buckyPositionX -= 2;
        if(buckyPositionX<-776){
            buckyPositionX += 2;
    }}}   
    public int getID(){
        return 1;
    }}
```

The code shows two rectangles (rectOne and rectTwo) rectOne is on top of the player and rectTwo should be on top of the house on the map, this does not happen, both recangles move together, remember, I mentioned that the map is moving and the player is staying still, the map is set to coordinates buckyPositionX and buckyPositionY and the player is set to shiftX and shiftY which is the centre of the screen, this can be replaced with constants if required as the player doesn't move, all if statements under the update method modify buckyPositionX and buckyPositonY that means that they move the map, so rectTwo (which is the house) also has to move whilst rectOne (the player rectangle) stays still, this is why I have used the variables buckyPositionX and buckyPoitionY for the rectTwo, but however my problem still occurs so there must be something wrong.

////////////EDIT - paragraph deleted to make post shorter//////////////

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying here... You say when you move one rectangle, the other moves, but I don't see anywhere in that code that you're moving either rectangle. Both of your rectangles are created at specific coordinates and never change.

Do you mean when you move bucky that both rectangles move?

Comment: Consider reducing your post. It is considered polite to carefully edit what you write, for the benefit of your readers (who are, after all, trying to help you).

Comment: I am sorry for the long post but whenever I tried making a shorter version of this question in the past I got my post either deleted or get told that the question is not being understood because of the lack of detail, however I will try delete what is not as necessary for now until it gets asked about. @Mike the if statements under the update method change buckypositionX and buckyPosiyionY which are also the coordinates for rectTwo.

Comment: rectTwo does not keep references to buckypositionX and buckypositionY, it simply uses their value at the time you construct the rectangles. If you wish to have to position of the rectangle change as bucky's position changes you will have to manually update the rectangle's coordinates. The same applies to rectOne. You set it's position on the screen based on the initial shiftX and shiftY values, but the location is not updated as shiftX and shiftY change.

Comment: You should also note that when drawing the rectangles you don't take into account the shiftX and shiftY values. As a result the rectangles would remain in a constant location on the screen as bucky (who does take into account shiftX and shiftY) moves. The result is that both would appear to move relative to bucky.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I understand what you mean when you say that the rectangle needs to be updated but I do not know how to update it because if I make the rectangle in my update method then my render method will not be able to find and use it, could you please show me how I would update it? Also, the shiftX and shiftY variables do not really need to be there, they can be constants as they are just the coordinates for the centre of the screen but as they get used a lot I made them a variable so that if needed in the future I could edit them easily.